# How do I install Adium themes in Empathy?

Tags: 11.10, themes, empathy

I had used the Adium themes in empathy in Ubuntu 11.04 but the same did not work for 11.10. Is there any workaround to enable the themes for empathy in 11.10

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still install them manually by downloading the themes, then extracting them to *~/.local/share/adium/message-styles*, that will make your downloaded themes available in Empathy. Certainly not as fun as using an install script, however it's guaranteed to work.

Comment: i have them installed in /usr/share/adium/message-style and when i copied the folder "message-style" to /.local/share/adium/message-style. i deleted the ones that were duplicated but still i can't see the one i have downloaded

Comment: It should be `message-styles` and if you want it system wide you can use `/usr/share/adium` and if you want it just for yourself use `~/.local/share/adium` paths